# Chromium Browser for wrapping HTML app into Android apps

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am working with Windows 7. I have an HTML web app that I want to wrap into mobile app using Chromium based browser engine.

In the past, I used Crosswalk Project but Crosswalk seems to have been canceled by the creator. I am trying to source a list of Chromium browser Android app wrappers for HTML apps or any other good technologies for wrapping my HTML app into mobile applications.

```
<html><head>
<title>My First Mobile App</title></head>

<body>
<h2>My First Mobile App.</h2>
Welcome to Stackoverflow.com
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The purpose of Crosswalk was to enable a consistent HTML5 engine for pre-Android 5 (2014) devices. Unless you have a need to support such devices, [WebViews are updated via the Play Store](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/webview/), [Apache Cordova (was Phonegap)](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/) exists, and there are other technologies like [Progressive Web Apps](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/) which allows for app-like behavior in browser.

Comment: @Morrison Chang Thanks for contribution so far

Comment: Android has Android System WebView. You don't need use 3d party web views.